# How XenCenter detects change quickly?

Tags: xen, xenapp

I am using Xenserver API for my application. I am storing some data in my application but I saw when I start or shutdown any VM, XenCenter detects it quickly. Is there any flag or any quick way to detect the change? Or I have to load all the data and then compare with the saved data?

Comment: What is your question ? How xencenter detects changes or the last one? Your last one is confusing and not clear that what you want to do ?

Comment: please answer the first one.